# SPARQL performance in property path query Sesame / rdf4j

Tags: sparql, sesame, rdf4j

Let's say I want to find all subjects which are connected with objects via property path. The connection could be represented:

```
Subject - prop 1 -> A - prop 2 -> B - prop 3 -> Object
```

This could be achieved by quite simple SPARQL query:

```
SELECT ?s WHERE {
    ?s prop1/prop2/prop3 ?o .
    VALUES ?o { <uri1> ... <urin> }
}
```

But I also want to include paths which use subclasses of A and/or B:

```
Subject - prop 1 -> subclassOfA - prop 2 -> subclassOfB - prop 3 -> Object
```

To achieve this I've added intermediate "sublassOf" property into the the path:

```
SELECT ?s WHERE {
    ?s prop1/<subclassOf>*/prop2/<subclassOf>*/prop3 ?o .
    VALUES ?o { <uri1> ... <urin> }
}
```

This worked really fast on my dataset in Sesame 2.7.2, but after migrating to rdf4j 2.5.2 this query just hangs. The question is whether this is the correct way of querying this way or there's something much more efficient? And what could've caused such a significant performance drop in the new versions?

Comment: When you say you want to “include paths which use subclasses of A and/or B” it's not clear what you mean by that. Do your paths actually connect _classes_ or do they connect _instances of specific classes_? Do you mean to include paths such as “subject --p1--> subClassOfA --sco--> A --p2--> subClassOfB --sco--> B --p3--> object”? Can you give a fuller example?

Comment: I'm wondering what `prop1, prop2, prop3` would be given that `rdfs:subClassOf` is primarily used for classes. Some sample data + expected result would be helpful. Moreover, you should open a ticket on the RDF4J Github project given that there is some performance regression with the property path

Comment: Fwiw between Sesame 2.7 (released in 2013) and rdf4j 2.5 (2018) there have been _a lot_ of bug fixes and improvements in how property paths in particular, and query planning more generally, works. Overall, performance has improved, but there's always corner cases of course. Like AKSW suggests, your best bet is to log a ticket with us detailing your use case and the shape of your data, so we can try to reproduce and see where the bottleneck is.

Comment: @cygri Thanks! In my dataset every resource is a Class. `A rdf:type rdfs:Class` and `subClassOfA rdf:type rdfs:Class`. They connected `subClassOfA rdfs:subClassOf A`. So the path you suggested is more correct. And `rdfs:subClassOf` is optional since it could be any subclass of A, any it's subclass or A itself.

Comment: @AKSW Thanks! Every resource is a Class `rdf:type rdfs:Class`. Properties are just custom properties `uri rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty` with labels.

Comment: @JeenBroekstra Thanks! I'll remove all sensitive data from the dataset and post a ticket. Meanwhile could you suggest me any sources to learn more about query planning?

Comment: ok, but I'm still wondering how a class is used in combination with a property unless you want to use OWL punning? Are you aware of the fact and what punning is? `:clsA :someProperty :someVal` makes `clsA` being an individual (under OWL 2 semantics at least, for RDF and SPARQL it doesn't matter). Please give some domain example.

Comment: I'll prepare an example. Maybe you could answer whether punning could have any effect if I'm using memory store with an empty ruleset?